# Adding a domain user in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

Before I ask my question, let me mention that my SQL Server is installed on a member server of a domain (it belongs to the domain but is not an AD server).

I am having trouble adding a network user in SQL Server Management Studio.

First I tried adding a user by right-clicking security and clicking `new -> login`. I wanted to add a network user, so I clicked locations.  But only the name of the local server was showing. I was unable to browse my domain users (at that time I was logged in through a network user on my SQL Server machine).

So I tried another approach.  I tried to add a network user through Transact-SQL as follows:

```
create login [domain\user] from windows;
```

But I got an error message saying - `Windows NT user or group not found` - even though the user existed on my domain server.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please let us know your version of SQL Server and other software you are working with to make it easier to answer your question? =)

Comment: Are you sure that the server is joined to that domain from where you are trying to add the user from?

Answer (score 1):

For me it worked to generate a script with SSMS.

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE LOGIN [domain\user] FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master]
GO
ALTER SERVER ROLE [role] ADD MEMBER [domian\user]
GO
```